# Migrating to an External Database teamCity Full Migration

Tags: postgresql, jetbrains, миграция, teamcity, hsqldb

Пытаюсь мигрировать TC с HSQLDB на Postgresql.

TC версии 2018, Postgresql 10

jdbc отсюда https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#current

Читаю доку тут https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Migrating+to+an+External+Database#MigratingtoanExternalDatabase-backup_restore
Хочу Full Migration

На 4 шаге Full Migration возникает ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

database.postgresql.properties.dist содержит

```
connectionUrl=jdbc:postgresql://#.#.#.#:5432;databaseName=#
connectionProperties.user=#
connectionProperties.password=#
```

Лог после изменения

> [2018-07-18 12:09:57,702]   INFO - Command line arguments: migrate -A
>   C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity -T
>   C:\TeamCity\conf\database.postgresql.properties [2018-07-18
>   12:09:57,827]   INFO - Using TeamCity data directory:
>   C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity [2018-07-18 12:09:57,827]   INFO -
>   Using database settings from the TeamCity data directory for source
>   database: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\config\database.properties
>   [2018-07-18 12:09:57,998]   INFO - Using source database  database
>   type: HSQLDB2     connection string:
>   jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity/system/buildserver
>   [2018-07-18 12:10:01,825]  ERROR - Failed: Unexpected exception: SQL
>   error when doing 'Taking a connection from the data source':
>   java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line:
>   C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver 45. Caused by:
>   org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file line:
>   C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver 45

```
         at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFunctions.create(DBFunctions.ja
va:227)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager.createNew
DBFunctions(TeamCityDatabaseManager.java:770)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager.connect(T
eamCityDatabaseManager.java:584)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.ensu
reSourceDB(BackupRestoreRunner.java:1783)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.run(
BackupRestoreRunner.java:818)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.main
0(BackupRestoreRunner.java:792)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.main
(BackupRestoreRunner.java:766)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: file input/output errorerror java.io.FileNo
tFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver.data (╬Єър
чрэю т фюёЄєях) opening file - file C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity/system/bui
ldserver.data
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Error.java:136)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.open(DataFileCache.java:396)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.getCache(Log.java:554)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.getCache(Logger.java:936)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.newStore(Logger.java:1416)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.PersistentStoreCollectionDatabase.getStore(Persist
entStoreCollectionDatabase.java:74)
        at org.hsqldb.Table.getRowStore(Table.java:2987)
        at org.hsqldb.TableBase.isEmpty(TableBase.java:580)
        at org.hsqldb.TableWorks.addIndex(TableWorks.java:593)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.getResult(StatementSchema.java:1299)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.execute(StatementSchema.java:268)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Session.java:1378)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(ScriptReaderText.java:11
7)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\syst
em\buildserver.data (╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFile.<init>(RAFile.java:182)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFile.newScaledRAFile(RAFile.java:164)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.open(DataFileCache.java:349)
        ... 31 more
DataFileCache.open
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildser
ver.data (╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFile.<init>(RAFile.java:182)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFile.newScaledRAFile(RAFile.java:164)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.open(DataFileCache.java:349)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.getCache(Log.java:554)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.getCache(Logger.java:936)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.newStore(Logger.java:1416)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.PersistentStoreCollectionDatabase.getStore(Persist
entStoreCollectionDatabase.java:74)
        at org.hsqldb.Table.getRowStore(Table.java:2987)
        at org.hsqldb.TableBase.isEmpty(TableBase.java:580)
        at org.hsqldb.TableWorks.addIndex(TableWorks.java:593)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.getResult(StatementSchema.java:1299)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.execute(StatementSchema.java:268)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Session.java:1378)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(ScriptReaderText.java:11
7)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(ScriptReaderBase.java:63
)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Log.java:778)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Log.java:181)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Logger.java:387)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Database.java:240)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Database.java:205)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:254)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(DatabaseManager.java:156)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(JDBCConnection.java:3593)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(JDBCDriver.java:312)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(JDBCDriver.java:260)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.jdbcLoader.JdbcDataSource.getConn
ection(JdbcDataSource.java:158)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFunctions.create(DBFunctions.ja
va:241)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFunctions.create(DBFunctions.ja
va:227)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager.createNew
DBFunctions(TeamCityDatabaseManager.java:770)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager.connect(T
eamCityDatabaseManager.java:584)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.ensu
reSourceDB(BackupRestoreRunner.java:1783)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.run(
BackupRestoreRunner.java:818)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.main
0(BackupRestoreRunner.java:792)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.main
(BackupRestoreRunner.java:766)
file input/output errorerror java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBr
ains\TeamCity\system\buildserver.data (╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях) opening file - file C
:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity/system/buildserver.data in statement [CREATE IN
DEX BACKUP_INFO_FILE_I ON PUBLIC.BACKUP_INFO(FILE_NAME)]
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: file input/output errorerror java.io.FileNotFoundExcep
tion: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver.data (╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄ
єях) opening file - file C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity/system/buildserver.da
ta
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Error.java:136)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.open(DataFileCache.java:396)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.getCache(Log.java:554)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.getCache(Logger.java:936)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.newStore(Logger.java:1416)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.PersistentStoreCollectionDatabase.getStore(Persist
entStoreCollectionDatabase.java:74)
        at org.hsqldb.Table.getRowStore(Table.java:2987)
        at org.hsqldb.TableBase.isEmpty(TableBase.java:580)
        at org.hsqldb.TableWorks.addIndex(TableWorks.java:593)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.getResult(StatementSchema.java:1299)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.execute(StatementSchema.java:268)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Session.java:1378)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(ScriptReaderText.java:11
7)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(ScriptReaderBase.java:63
)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Log.java:778)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Log.java:181)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Logger.java:387)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Database.java:240)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Database.java:205)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:254)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(DatabaseManager.java:156)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(JDBCConnection.java:3593)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(JDBCDriver.java:312)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(JDBCDriver.java:260)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.jdbcLoader.JdbcDataSource.getConn
ection(JdbcDataSource.java:158)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFunctions.create(DBFunctions.ja
va:241)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFunctions.create(DBFunctions.ja
va:227)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager.createNew
DBFunctions(TeamCityDatabaseManager.java:770)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager.connect(T
eamCityDatabaseManager.java:584)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.ensu
reSourceDB(BackupRestoreRunner.java:1783)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.run(
BackupRestoreRunner.java:818)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.main
0(BackupRestoreRunner.java:792)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.main
(BackupRestoreRunner.java:766)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\syst
em\buildserver.data (╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFile.<init>(RAFile.java:182)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFile.newScaledRAFile(RAFile.java:164)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.open(DataFileCache.java:349)
        ... 31 more
Script processing failure
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file line: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\Te
amCity\system\buildserver 45
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Error.java:136)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(ScriptReaderText.java:14
8)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(ScriptReaderBase.java:63
)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Log.java:778)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Log.java:181)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Logger.java:387)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Database.java:240)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Database.java:205)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:254)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(DatabaseManager.java:156)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(JDBCConnection.java:3593)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(JDBCDriver.java:312)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(JDBCDriver.java:260)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.jdbcLoader.JdbcDataSource.getConn
ection(JdbcDataSource.java:158)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFunctions.create(DBFunctions.ja
va:241)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFunctions.create(DBFunctions.ja
va:227)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager.createNew
DBFunctions(TeamCityDatabaseManager.java:770)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager.connect(T
eamCityDatabaseManager.java:584)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.ensu
reSourceDB(BackupRestoreRunner.java:1783)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.run(
BackupRestoreRunner.java:818)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.main
0(BackupRestoreRunner.java:792)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.main
(BackupRestoreRunner.java:766)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: file input/output errorerror java.io.FileNo
tFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver.data (╬Єър
чрэю т фюёЄєях) opening file - file C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity/system/bui
ldserver.data
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Error.java:136)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.open(DataFileCache.java:396)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.getCache(Log.java:554)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.getCache(Logger.java:936)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.newStore(Logger.java:1416)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.PersistentStoreCollectionDatabase.getStore(Persist
entStoreCollectionDatabase.java:74)
        at org.hsqldb.Table.getRowStore(Table.java:2987)
        at org.hsqldb.TableBase.isEmpty(TableBase.java:580)
        at org.hsqldb.TableWorks.addIndex(TableWorks.java:593)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.getResult(StatementSchema.java:1299)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.execute(StatementSchema.java:268)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Session.java:1378)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(ScriptReaderText.java:11
7)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\syst
em\buildserver.data (╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFile.<init>(RAFile.java:182)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFile.newScaledRAFile(RAFile.java:164)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.open(DataFileCache.java:349)
        ... 31 more
could not reopen database
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file line: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\Te
amCity\system\buildserver 45
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Error.java:136)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(ScriptReaderText.java:14
8)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(ScriptReaderBase.java:63
)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Log.java:778)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Log.java:181)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Logger.java:387)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Database.java:240)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Database.java:205)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:254)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(DatabaseManager.java:156)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(JDBCConnection.java:3593)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(JDBCDriver.java:312)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(JDBCDriver.java:260)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.jdbcLoader.JdbcDataSource.getConn
ection(JdbcDataSource.java:158)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFunctions.create(DBFunctions.ja
va:241)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.DBFunctions.create(DBFunctions.ja
va:227)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager.createNew
DBFunctions(TeamCityDatabaseManager.java:770)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.db.TeamCityDatabaseManager.connect(T
eamCityDatabaseManager.java:584)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.ensu
reSourceDB(BackupRestoreRunner.java:1783)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.run(
BackupRestoreRunner.java:818)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.main
0(BackupRestoreRunner.java:792)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.maintenance.BackupRestoreRunner.main
(BackupRestoreRunner.java:766)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: file input/output errorerror java.io.FileNo
tFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver.data (╬Єър
чрэю т фюёЄєях) opening file - file C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity/system/bui
ldserver.data
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Error.java:136)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.open(DataFileCache.java:396)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.getCache(Log.java:554)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.getCache(Logger.java:936)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.newStore(Logger.java:1416)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.PersistentStoreCollectionDatabase.getStore(Persist
entStoreCollectionDatabase.java:74)
        at org.hsqldb.Table.getRowStore(Table.java:2987)
        at org.hsqldb.TableBase.isEmpty(TableBase.java:580)
        at org.hsqldb.TableWorks.addIndex(TableWorks.java:593)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.getResult(StatementSchema.java:1299)
        at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.execute(StatementSchema.java:268)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Session.java:1378)
        at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(ScriptReaderText.java:11
7)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\syst
em\buildserver.data (╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFile.<init>(RAFile.java:182)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFile.newScaledRAFile(RAFile.java:164)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.open(DataFileCache.java:349)
        ... 31 more
Failed: Unexpected exception: SQL error when doing 'Taking a connection from the
 data source': java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: C:\ProgramData\
JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver 45. Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: e
rror in script file line: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver 4
5
Done.
```

Comment: не могли бы вместо картинки предоставить лог в виде текст? просто скопируйте текст с консоли и вставьте в тело вопроса

Comment: вам надо указать `database.properties` вместо `database.properties.dist`, и надеюсь, что //#.#.#.#:5432 вы специально заменили, а не на самом деле.

Comment: специально. dist изменил

Comment: то есть изменили на database.properties и ошибка такая же осталась?

Comment: Убрал dist. Изменил пути в команде т.к. до этого они были не корректны.

Comment: Лог добивил к теме

Comment: это точно весь лог? в логе еще должен быть трейс полный

Comment: Да, это то что в логах. Все подробности в cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что база повреждена. 
Похожая проблема https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206158469-SQL-error-when-doing-Taking-a-connection-from-the-data-source

Вам нужно будет попробовать восстановить базу и после попытаться еще раз. 
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Common+Problems#CommonProblems-Database-relatedissues

Напоминаю, что версии DB можно обновлять только вверх.